# How to prevent gitlab pipeline from running twice when pushing a tag

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a gitlab pipeline which looks like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script: //do stuff

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: //do stuff
  only:
    - /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+
  when: on_success
```

I want it to run build job for every commit, and run the deploy step if it has a tag matching the regex.
It almost works, but it runs twice when I push it with tag, once with deploy step and once without it. How can I prevent that?

Comment: did you try `/^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+/`?

Comment: The actual regex is actually a bit more complex and it does end with /, I simplified it for the sake of example.

The issue seems to be that it triggers once because commit has been pushed to develop branch, and once more because a tag has been pushed

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is the [expected behavior](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/13445) - tags trigger a separate pipeline, even when they are part of the same push as the commit. You can block this with [workflows](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html), but in your case it would prevent the deploy job from running.

You can prevent the same job running in both pipelines with [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules), which is now recommended over only/except. It's very flexible when combined with [CI/CD vars](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html). I would try the bash regex operator with `CI_COMMIT_TAG`:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script: //do stuff
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ "<your_regex>"'
      when: never
    - when: always

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: //do stuff
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ "<your_regex>"'
      when: always
    - when: never
```

Rules are read top to bottom until a match is found. The catch-all rules at the end ensure that:

- `build` always runs unless the regex matches
- `deploy` only runs when the regex matches

This will still create 2 pipelines, but it should prevent the build job from running twice and wasting minutes.